# Why am I losing my Angular 6 Service object variable when I refresh the component it injected into?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a SERVICE test.service that has an object

```
 public locationObject = {
   ......
   ......
   currency: string
}
```

This SERVICE is injected into my HeaderComponent and the object locationObject is initialized in ngOnInit....so far so good. When a user logs in...I use router.navigate to send the user to a dashboard

```
 ..
this.router.navigate(['owner-dashboard']);
```

The SERVICE is also injected in the loginComponent
and the ownerDashboardComponent....so far so good.
I can now access the properties of locationObject in ownerDashboardComponent.

however if I refresh my screen I have lost locationObject it is now undefined.
I also noticed that after while the header component completes its refresh and the locationObject is now reset. 
This brings forth another questions. So refreshing the screen also refresh the header but why do I lose locationObj?

I think I have a vague idea what's going on here but can some explain it to me.....Thanks.

EDIT.
core html:

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing the screen? Refreshing page by browser's refresh function?

Comment: hard to tell what's going on without seeing more of your code. hard to tell how your header relates to your dashboard and what you are routing to and from.

Comment: @ThaFog if I hit reload button on the browser

Comment: @Rick I edit the question to include the header routing html. There's no other relationship between the header on the components. The header calls the Service functions to initialize stuff.

Comment: @Rick I don't want to over complicate the question...so simple put you access the header/home page by  www.abbc.com...you then login in and routed to a dashboard. The problem seems to be when I refresh the header is also refreshed but takes longer to completes the initialization before the component is ready of the locationObject??

Comment: yeah I guess I'm not familiar with the concept of "I have a service that has an object". my services are just a group of functions that get called from the other components. usually in ngOnInit(). So hitting refresh always refreshes everything fully.

Comment: if you refresh a angular app , then data stored in the variables will be reset to default. 
if you have a use case where you need data even after refresh , then use session / local storage concept with your logic accordingly.

Comment: @LogicBlower you guys are correct I am just trying to understand more clearly how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around browser refresh, u have to use local storage or something similar. Store the variable data in local storage.